# How I can get Google Talk History?

Tags: java, gmail, google-talk, jakarta-mail

I want to get all mails from all folders from google.
I try do this with javax.mail.
I retrieve folders list by such code:

```
imapSslStore.getDefaultFolder().list("*");
```

But there are not folder with name "Chat" since I can see "Chats" label in Google mails interface.

Answer (score 2):

Gmail's chats are not visible to IMAP connections. The folder is disabled in the Gmail's settings UI.

Even using IMAP search is not going to find anything in the chat folder.